# What is this black residue on the refrigerant lines of my subzero refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

I have an old 1980s subzero refrigerator that is powering up but no longer cooling effectively. It appears at some point the compressors were replaced with r134a.

There is a black char/blob/residue on the refrigerant lines going into and out of the freezer evaporator on the top of the unit. It feels reasonably hard to the touch and did not stick when I poked it.

Is this residue from compressor oil leaking and is indicative of a leak, or is it just burnt insulation? Or something else?
[image: fridge with residue]

Comment: what insulation ?

Comment: The black tube that goes up and left is insulation for the refrigerant line.

Comment: Kinda just looks like aged insulation to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black sticky putty was commonly used in the 80s as insulation on refrigerant lines and to bind things like sensor bulbs to lines. In time it would get hard just like plumbers putty.

Looks like you have some of that.